# From DNF to CNF

Tags: logic, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

What is the most efficient way to switch from [DNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) to [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method with complete enumeration of 2^n terms is described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054911/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51857.html).

A suitable tool would be `bc2cnf` (http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/bcsat/).
To use `bc2cnf`, you'd have to express the `DNF` terms as "AND gates" in `bc2cnf` syntax.

Example for a `EXOR` function with four inputs and eight `DNF` minterms:

```
BC1.1
_m1 := !A & !B & !C &  D;
_m2 := !A & !B &  C & !D;
_m4 := !A &  B & !C & !D;
_m7 := !A &  B &  C &  D;
_m8 :=  A & !B & !C & !D;
_m11 := A & !B &  C &  D;
_m13 := A &  B & !C &  D;
_m14 := A &  B &  C & !D;
_F := _m1 | _m2 | _m4 | _m7 | _m8 | _m11 | _m13 | _m14;
ASSIGN _F;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that there exists transformations, such as Tseitin transformation, which allows for a transformation from any propositional formula to CNF while avoiding an exponential blow up in terms.